# ActionSheet Source View BarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uialertcontroller, uipopover

I have a bar button item in the navigation bar that when pressed, will present a `UIAlertController` with the style as `.ActionSheet`. In the iPhone it appears just the way that I want. For the iPad I know I need to add

```
// For iPad, set the pop over bounds
var popOver = optionMenu.popoverPresentationController
popOver?.sourceView = button as UIView
popOver?.sourceRect = (button as UIView).bounds
popOver?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
```

Does anyone know of a way to use the bar button item as the `sourceView` and the `sourceRect`? I would like the popover to point to the bar button item.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just use `popOver?.barButtonItem = myBarButtonItem`

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks I don't see how I missed that.